# How to write a string with padding to binary file using fwrite?

Tags: c++, string, binary, fwrite

My requirement is to write a "32-byte string indicating the units of pressure" to a binary file. The units of pressure I am wanting to write is "Pa" as a 32-byte string. And here is my attempt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen ("input_file.dat", "wb");
  //Units
  string units = "Pa";
  //Write Units
  fwrite (&units, 1, 32, myFile);
  fclose (myFile);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting (conversion of Pa to binary in 32 bytes). The "00100000" are spaces. How do I append those to just Pa?

01010000 01100001 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000 00100000

However, I'm seeing

[image: Output when I compile and run the above code]

Comment: Why append spaces at all? Simply write `"Pa"` as a 32-byte block and then it will be available when you read that 32-bytes back in. Writing all 32-bytes will write the *nul-terminating* character as well, so you can treat those 32-bytes as a string when you read the block back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `"Pa"` is only 2 bytes (3 if you count the null terminator), but you want to write out 32 bytes to your file. So you need to pad the string with 30 space characters. There are many different ways you can handle this:

```cpp
char units[32] = "Pa";
memset(units+2, ' ', 30);
fwrite (units, 1, 32, myFile);
```

```cpp
std::string units = "Pa";
std::string padding(32-units.size(), ' ');
fwrite (units.c_str(), 1, units.size(), myFile);
fwrite (padding.c_str(), 1, padding.size(), myFile);
```

```cpp
std::string units = "Pa";
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::setw(32) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << units;
std::string s = oss.str();
fwrite (s.c_str(), 1, s.size(), myFile);
```

That being said, since you are using C++, you should be using C++ style file I/O instead of C style file I/O, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream myFile ("input_file.dat", ios::binary);
    string units = "Pa";
    myFile << setw(32) << setfill(' ') << left << units;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your second suggestion and it works like I need it to. Appreciate the help and introduction to padding!

Comment: I also tried the C++ style file I/O and got this error. 
teststring.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
teststring.cpp:9:19: error: variable ‘std::ofstream myFile’ has initializer but incomplete type
   ofstream myFile ("input_file.dat", ios::binary);

Comment: @SuganthiSelvaraj do you have `#include <fstream>` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a string directly to a file, you are writing the contents of the `string` class to your file, this is probably something like a pointer and a size, not the character data.

The simple fix is to make the following change to write the character data (this includes a null terminator, if you don't want that remove the `+1`):

```
fwrite (units.c_str(), 1, units.size() + 1, myFile);
```

The other alternative is to use c++ streams which can write a string directly:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::ofstream myFile("input_file.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
  //Units
  string units = "Pa";
  //Write Units
  myFile << units;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `fwrite()` example is writing out the null terminator, but your `cout` example is not.

Comment: Thanks! The fwrite suggestion worked for me. However, I am still not sure how to fill the remaining 30 bits with a space without manually adding spaces to the string. Similar to the null, could I add spaces?

Comment: @SuganthiSelvaraj see the answer I just posted