# Convert fwrite to C++ type code to write binary files

Tags: c++, integer, binaryfiles, fwrite

I am trying to convert C style file IO into C++ style file IO. I need to write the number 42 as a 4-byte signed integer.

Here's an example of what C type IO that I tried that worked

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen ("input_file.dat", "wb");

  int magicn = 42;
  fwrite (&magicn, sizeof(magicn), 1, myFile);

  fclose (myFile);
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to convert the above code to C++ type IO based on a suggestion from a different question I asked ([How to write a string with padding to binary file using fwrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258898/how-to-write-a-string-with-padding-to-binary-file-using-fwrite)).

Here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream myFile ("input_file.dat", ios::binary);
  int magicn = 42;
  myFile << setw(sizeof(magicn)) << magicn;
  myFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

However, the output I am expecting when I use the 'xxd -b input_file.dat' command is not the same.

The output I am expecting is (generated with C type IO code)

0000000: 00101010 00000000 00000000 00000000                    *...

But I see (generated with my attempt of C++ type IO code)

0000000: 00100000 00100000 00110100 00110010                      42

Looking for a solution. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Don't use formatted I/o meant for human readable text when you want binary I/o. Use the `write()` ostream method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

```
myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&magicn), sizeof(magicn));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is more like `fprintf(myFile, "%d", magicn)`. That is, it performs *formatted* insertion to the stream, so you end up with the ASCII code for the 42nd ASCII character.

The analogue of `fwrite` is `ostream::write`. Just look at the available members of `ostream` to find out what you can do with it.